# Store same values for different key. [Java]

Tags: java, hashmap, store

I'm trying to create a list that contains a value and a key, but I want the value to stay the same, and just have multiple keys.
So this is just an example:

```java
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        String str = "hey";
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
             map.put(str, i);
        }
```

This is just an example.
But how would I go about adding the same string and a different key? Do I need to not use HashMap or it is do-able with it? (because HashMap is not necessary for me, as long as it stores 2 values it's good for me)

Comment: key should be unique

Comment: You want i to be constanst or str?

Comment: Key is unique, I'm assigning it to a different "i" everytime, but it just overwrites the previous set with a new key.

Comment: @Destinations no, you're putting `str` as the key. It's `put(key, value)`.

Comment: Looks like you have hard coded the key, which does not really fit to your description. Maybe take a `Map<Integer, String>` and change the `for` loop to do `map.put(i, str);`? I think filling up a map with several different keys that all have the same value associated is not the way a `Map` should be used, but it will work, of course.

Comment: Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>(); if(map.get(key) != null then List<Integer> ints = map.get(key); ints.add(key); else  map.put(key, i);

Comment: omg @Kayaman , I feel like an idiot, problem fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map`  with a List or Set Value

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
String str = "hey";
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
 if(map.get(str) == null)  map.put(str, new HashSet<>());
 map.get(str).add(i);
}
```